# Event not firing all of the time from a thread to main thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events, delegates

I am currently experimenting on a c# code to perform interthread communication from a random thread to main thread.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public delegate void MyHandler<MyEventArgs>(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

public class thr : Form
{
    Button b1;
    ProgressBar pb;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new thr());
    }

    public thr()
    {
        b1 = new Button();
        b1.Text = "Open";

        pb = new ProgressBar();
        pb.Location = new Point(pb.Location.X, b1.Location.Y + b1.Size.Height + 5);
        pb.Step = 1;
        pb.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;

        this.Controls.Add(b1);
        this.Controls.Add(pb);

        b1.Click += (s, e) => { this.M_work(); };
    }

    private void M_work()
    {
        dhr obb = new dhr();
        obb.Ev1 += (s, e) => { pb.Value = e.PbVal; };
        ThreadStart tst = new ThreadStart(obb.prform);
        Thread thh = new Thread(tst);
        thh.Start();
        this.Text = obb.Txtt;
    }
}

class dhr
{
    public string Txtt;
    public event MyHandler<MyEventArgs> Ev1;

    public void prform()
    {
        int ab = 1;
        int cd = Int32.MaxValue - 3;
        int ef = 1;
        while(ef != cd)
        {
            if(ab % 2 == 0)
            {
                ab = 0;
                ef++;
            }
            ab++;
            if(this.Ev1 != null)
                this.Ev1.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs( (ef/cd) * 100 ) );
        }
        this.Txtt = ef.ToString();
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int PbVal;

    public MyEventArgs(int pbval)
    {
        this.PbVal = pbval;
    }
}
```

However I know a bit about BackgroundWorker and could have used in this code but I got hope in this when the progress bar gets updated to 100% at the end of the execution. It shows that obviously the event is firing but not all of the time. Is there anything I could add in this code to make it possible?

Comment: This is just the UI code. How exactly are you invoking the delegate from another thread ?

Comment: You are actually firing the event from within the worker thread.  Instead, you should do it from the UI thread.  You need to pass an instance of your form to your `dhr` class and use that instance to invoke the event.